# How to get resource in scheduler view when clicking on calendar

Tags: java, fullcalendar, vaadin

I'm playing around with fullcalendar scheduler view together with Vaadin 12. So far, so good and everything works fine. However, when I try to add an event for a resource, I'm unable to get the corresponding resource in my timeslot selected listener. Anybody a clue how to do that? Didn't find needful information in the documentation for the java API...

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, may you provide a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the addon, you may now use a specialized event types (required add-on versions FC 1.8.0 / scheduler 1.3.0).

The new events are part of the scheduler add on and provide resource information:

- TimeslotClickedSchedulerEvent
- TimeslotsSelectedSchedulerEvent

Usage example of timeslot selected event listener.

```
FullCalendarScheduler calendar = ...

// ...

calendar.addTimeslotsSelectedListener((TimeslotsSelectedSchedulerEvent event) -> {
    Optional<Resource> resource = event.getResource();
    // ... do something with the resource
});
```

Comment: I could already verify this fix and I can also confirm that it's working like a charm :-) Thanks for providing this enhancement that quickly! Very much appreciated and definitely an argument to consider your framework for further projects.